# npm Start and "npm run client" is not working in Node

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to run a Node js program as defined in [Github probyto](https://github.com/probyto/mern-fullstack-boilerplate/tree/main)

i am following all the steps defined in the above github link but when i try to run

```
npm run client
```

it gives me a error as

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@2.0.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@2.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Gautam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-11T07_55_54_943Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mern-jwt-auth@2.0.0 client: `npm start --prefix client`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mern-jwt-auth@2.0.0 client script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Gautam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-11T07_55_54_976Z-debug.log
```

I have already tried some solutions like

updating node/ npm

deleting node modules and packagelock.json file and then npm install

npm update

but nothing seems to work . can anyone help me run this . any help is appreciated

Comment: Run npm from folder where your package.json is located.

Comment: i ran "npm" from the folder as you said and it seems to be working fine . how can that fix my error?

Comment: what do you mean? you just have to run npm from the root package folder (where package.json is located).

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? Please don't tag spam.

Comment: did you run these two steps in root folder                                                                        1. npm run client-install                             
2.copy config/keys.sample.js config/keys.js                                                               then update keys.js file variables as per the requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [getting started](https://github.com/probyto/mern-fullstack-boilerplate#getting-started) page on their README.md shows you the steps you need to follow.

Simplified:

Run:

```
npm run client-install
```

(if using windows) Then run:

```
copy config/keys.sample.js config/keys.js
```

Or if using Mac, run:

```
cp config/keys.sample.js config/keys.js
```

Only then can you run the development server:

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I cloned the repo and tested it out for you and it doesn't seem to have any issue; all you need to do to make the client work is the following:

```
npm i; npm run client-install; npm run client
```

And with that you should see your react app compiling successfully

If, for some reason, the previous didn't work out for you, you can retry after cleaning up both your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` with the following (I know you tried already, but give this line of code a shot):

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json; cd client; rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json; cd ..; npm i; npm run client-install; npm run client
```

Last try I'd give, if still not working, is about installing the modules directly from the client folder, as such:

```
cd client; rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json; npm i; npm start
```

With these steps it should definitely be up and running successfully, but if not you may need to debug a bit further.

For that, I specifically mean to check there are no issues while running the module installation and finally check if you are downloading the modules from the right registry. To do that, just run `npm config ls -l` on any folder, and check to have the `registry` property set as `"https://registry.npmjs.org/"`

Hope will help!

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this in client folder.

STEP #1:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

STEP #2:

Since you are using Windows, delete node_modules folder and package_lock.json file manually.

STEP #3:

```
npm install
```

STEP #4:

```
npm start
```

Many people are using this method to solve situations like you.

Hope this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I resolved by using below commands

sudo npm cache clean -f

sudo npm install -g n

sudo n stable

To upgrade to latest version (and not current stable) version, you can use

sudo n latest

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you don't install all needed packages.
In documentation for project have some step those you skip.
After install packages you need run command for install additional packages.

```
npm run client-install
```

And after this run project with:

```
npm run client
```