# Install Node.js on linux 32 bit

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, linux, 32-bit

How can I install latest version of node.js which is (node.js 16) on 32 bit Linux? I can't do it with apt package manager bcuz the latest version of node.js available  on apt is version 8.

Comment: You can download binaries for various architectures [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/). If there's no pre-built binary for your platform, you can [build from source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md#building-nodejs-on-supported-platforms) locally.

Comment: Why 32-bit? 64-bit operating systems have been the norm for a long time. Is this some special embedded environment?

Comment: You can try to install [`n`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) with `npm install -g n`. Then you can install Node.js version 16 with `n 16`. `n` is a Node.js version manager.

Comment: You could use nvm, https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: @jabaa  Nice, never seen that one.  I suppose it's similar to nvm, but using node.  Seems a cleaner solution..

Comment: try this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65663207/npm-start-and-npm-run-client-is-not-working-in-node/65805890#65805890

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an unofficial build, navigate through the site for different versions and download the tar file for the build you want: https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v16.7.0/

Comment: Yes I did it before asking question. I downloaded an tar.gz file and extracted that. now I don't know how to install it bcuz it has no any installing file.

Comment: @MoeinRezaie - You don't have to "install" it. Just put whatever directory has the `node` executable in it in your path (even that is technically optional, but makes it convenient). (Usually it's a `bin` folder under wherever you expanded the archive to.)

Answer (score 0):

Build from the source code.

Not all app came from package managers. Sometimes you have to build it from the source. My guess that it possible, because I spent not more than 5 minutes for just google and don`t do any "scuba diving" into the problem.

### ReadMe: [link](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md),

### SourceCode: [link](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/)

My advice - try it, because nodejs is supporting windows x32, so I guess you can try to build it on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), you can install it following these commands in your terminal:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
```

After it installed your must run this command:

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

and run `nvm`

After all of this process, you can install a specific node version using `nvm install NUMBER_VERSION` i.e, `nvm install 14` and when installation will be completed you can run `nvm use 14` and `nvm alias default 14` .

I hope this could be useful for you.